# changed my screen resolution on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

i put a new operating system in my lap.but my screen resolution is changed on my windows .my display ,icons,file  is expand and stressed type. how to put a new screen resolution software so please help me ,to get a perfect display.

Answer (score 1):

Right click anywhere on your desktop, select Screen Resolution. From there you can adjust your screen resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install drivers for your newly installed Operating System in your laptop. You can install them from the rescue disk/drivers disk you might have got it with your laptop or visit website of your laptop manufacturer and get drivers from support section.